# Create wrapper LWC for javascript static resource?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, static-resources

I want to use a Javascript library to process some information without reimplementing the entire library in apex is there any way I could embed it in a web component then access it via post method?

I want to access this from either a trigger/scheduled/flow action (not a screen flow)

Comment: You might need to expand your question a bit. Where do you want to access this library from (visualforce page, another web component, trigger, etc)?

Comment: for use in a trigger/scheduled/called from an action

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do what you are asking to do. That is, you cannot host a service in  lwc using some already existing library and call that service from apex.

In such cases, we typically implement them as externally hosted cloud functions (GCP)/lambda functions (AWS) and call that from apex.

Comment: mmm figured this might be the response we were looking at salesforce functions or azure / aws functions